# special eclipse hotkey

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

Does eclipse have a hotkey to change the name of the function in all places, if I changed it in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALT + SHIFT + R`, than enter the new name and press `Enter`. Every reference in your workspace will be updated!